# Return 1,0 after looking through multiple scenarios if any are true

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need column J to look at multiple different scenarios and return 1,0 if any are true.

In J1 (and continuing down column J)

if B1 is a number and
B2 and B3 are blank and
the sum of G1:G3 is 2 or more
or

if B1 is a number and B2 is a number or if B2 is "-" and B3 is a number

then return 1

However, if in the range of H1:H3 there is a FALSE,
then an additional row must be added to the sum of G1:G3.

If B1 is "-" then J1 is empty

EXAMPLES:

1. B1 is a number, B3 is also a number, so J1 should read 1
2. B11 Is a number. B12:B13 are "-". So then we look to the sum of G11:G13. That equals 2, so J11 should read 1.
3. B23 is a number, and B24:B25 are "-". So then we look to the sum of G23:G25. However H25 is False, so now we look to the sum of G23:G26. If H24 is false too, then we would look to the sum of G23:G27.

One goal is to always add three applicable values from G, looking at H to determine applicable values.

I could split up these formulas into multiple columns if needed.

[SAMPLE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yp590RZOO2V0-WnDtZnFh1xYo_5r8PI8PtFbdsECbJ8/edit?usp=sharing)

I worked out this formula

=if(B1="-","",if(or(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B1),SUM(G1:G3)>=2,B2="-",B3="-"),1),if(and(isnumber(B1),or(isnumber(B2),isnumber(B3))),1)),1))

But have no idea how to add the stipulation for column H when a FALSE is present.

Comment: What do you mean by ```UNLESS in the range of H1:H3 there is a FALSE, then an additional row must be added to the sum of G1:G3.```?

Comment: Sorry. I mistyped a few things. Post is correct now.  If there are no FALSE values in H1:H3, then sum G1:G3. If there is one FALSE value, then sum G1:G4. If there are 2 FALSE values in H1:H3, then sum G1:G5